# Prices and addtocart button not showing in storefront magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

In my m2 store, Prices and addtocart button are not showing for any product, Can someone please help me with this,Why it is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check var/log to find the exact issue. There is a file exception.log which will contain all the information of bug. You can try by Reindex all the products and the deploy static content.